# tkinter not displaying window created in code

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to program a virtual pet in python for my desktop however, no window is being displayed when I run the following code. I am struggling to understand why no window is popping up when I run this code. This is the code where the tkinter display is being coded. I call the images and iterate over the frames because they are gifs then I configure the window and make its background transparent, finally I pack all the features together and loop the program. However, nothing is being displayed when I run the code.

```
import pyautogui
import random
import tkinter as tk

impath = r"/Users/antonioramos/Desktop/SummerResearch/"



window = tk.Tk()

idle = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'idle.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(5)]#idle gif

#window configuration
window.geometry("100x100")
window.config(highlightbackground='black')
label = tk.Label(window,bd=0,bg='black')
window.overrideredirect(True)
window.wm_attributes('-transparent',True)
label.pack()
#loop the program
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please reduce this down to a [mcve]. There is a whole lot of code that seems unnecessary to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Also why are you using indentation of 1 space? Usually people go for 4.

Comment: I have reduced the code to just the displaying of an image in a tkinter window but still don't get any window

Comment: Try getting rid of `window.overrideredirect(True)` and `window.wm_attributes('-transparent',True)`